# Capturing NFCSTATUS_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error in Ndef writeNdefMessage

Tags: android, nfc, ioexception, ndef

While writing to a NFC tag with Ndef.writeNdefMessage, I get an IOException error in the catch block. Checking Logcat showed that PhLibNfc_Ndef_Write function triggered  NFCSTATUS_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error, which effectively triggered the IOException. Is there any way to catch this NFCSTATUS_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error in the app layer. I googled a lot, but always ended up with the source code of the PhLibNfc_Ndef_Write function.

Code which I use to write to tag

```
final NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(bytearray);
final NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
if(ndefFormatable == null){
final Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
ndef.connect();
if(ndef.isConnected() && ndef.isWritable()){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // this logic is not working. Status quo remains
                int actlen = ndef.getMaxSize();
                if (actlen < arrayLen) {
                    Toast.makeText(tagHandler.this, "Space not available", 20).show();
                }
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(message); <-- error is triggered here
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start(); //runnable
ndef.close();
return true;
}
```

The logcat error which I encounter

```
E/NFC JNI(705): phLibNfc_Ndef_Write() returned 0x001f[NFCSTATUS_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
W/System.err(547): java.io.IOException
W/System.err(547):  at android.nfc.tech.Ndef.writeNdefMessage(Ndef.java:313)
W/System.err(547):  at com.example.tagreader.tagHandler$2.run(tagHandler.java:270)
W/System.err(547):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any help on capturing the NFCSTATUS_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before writing to the tag, call `getMaxSize()` on the `Ndef` technology. That tells you whether your message will fit, preventing the IOException altogether.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Though, there seems to be something more to the storage space failure, as even though the expected write data length is lower than the one got through Ndef.getTag(tag).getMaxSize(). Still am getting the NFCSTATUS error.

Comment: For a Mifare UL-C card, does getMaxSize() take into account the unprogrammable blocks (blocked using OTP bits)?

Comment: The calculation behind getMaxSize() is mainly based on the tag size declaration in page 3 of the card (the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag specification calls that the Capability Container). If some page reserved for NDEF storage are blocked by setting certain bits in page 2, this is not taken into account.